# Can I add a ListView or a GridView inside HeaderItem of another ListView? [UWP]

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have the following scenario.

```
          <GridView ItemsSource={Binding X} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource Y}/>
          <TextBlock Text={Binding Z} />
          <ListView ItemsSource={Binding K} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource P}/>
```

Now the whole thing needs to be scrollable, so I can put them inside a ScrollViewer like this,

```
    <ScrollViewer>

      <GridView ItemsSource={Binding X} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource Y}/>
      <TextBlock Text={Binding Z} />
      <ListView ItemsSource={Binding K} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource P}/>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

But apparently doing that kills the virtualization of `ListView`, so instead of doing that,  I am trying to put the `GridView` and `TextBlock` inside the `ListViewHeaderItem`. So that I can use the scrollviewer of the listview itself without using a separate scrollviewer, enabling the virtualization to take effect.

So, my question is can I put a gridView with a different itemsSource inside the headerItem of the list?  So far I have not been able to as the HeaderItem's data context seems to be the data context of the listview's ItemsSource. I have tried the following way.

```
     <ListView ItemsSource={Binding K} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource P}>

        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <GridView ItemsSource={Binding X} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource Y}/>
                <TextBlock Text={Binding Z} />

          </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you using {Binding} or {x:Bind}? The xaml in your sample with {Binding} should work as written, because by default the contents of HeaderTemplate will inherit the DataContext of the ListView.

Comment: "Binding" but I don't want to inherit ListView's DataContext , I want to give that a different data context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the HeaderTemplate contents to have a different DataContext to that of the parent list, you can use the ListView.Header property:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource={Binding K} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource P} Header={Binding HDC}>

    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <GridView ItemsSource={Binding X} ItemsTemplate={StaticResource Y}/>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Z} />

      </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Where the DataContext of the list is like this:

```
public class ListDataContext {
        public IEnumerable K {get;}
        public HeaderDataContext HDC {get;}

        public class HeaderDataContext {
                public IEnumerable X {get;}
                public string Z {get;}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't in a format I can readily test, but there are generally two ways to do this:

1) Give the parent window a name e.g. 'x:Name=_this' and then change your GridView binding to `ItemsSource={Binding X, ElementName=_this}`.

2) Use a DataProxy (see [this article](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) for code and description) and change your GridView binding to `ItemsSource={Binding Data.X, Source={StaticResource proxy}}`.

In my experience both worked with WPF but only the second worked with Xamarin. Haven't had to do this with UWP myself but you'll probably find at least one of them works.